# Add opacity slider to the color panel for one color well but not others

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscolorpanel, nscolorwell

I'd like to add a opacity slider to the NSColorPanel that is shown for 1 specific NSColorWell. All other color wells should not show the opacity slider.

I know I can set this for the sharedColorPanel like so:

```
 [[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] setShowsAlpha:YES];
```

But how do I do this when I only want this behavior for a single color well?

I tried adding an IBAction, but this IBAction is not called when you click the color well. (So I can't make any changes before the panel is displayed). It is called when you choose another color in the color panel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, here's the code that works. Set the colorwell class in IB to AlphaColorWell:**

```
@implementation AlphaColorWell

- (void)activate:(BOOL)exclusive
{
    [[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] setShowsAlpha:YES];
    [super activate:exclusive];
}

- (void)deactivate
{
    [super deactivate];
    [[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] setShowsAlpha:NO];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 7):

AppKit isn't showing the opacity slider in the panel because it thinks the app doesn't support alpha, which is the default. So rather than subclass, just do this:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    ...
    NSColor.ignoresAlpha = false
    ...
}
```

Comment: Most convenient and easy to implement solution :D Still works

Answer (score 3):

```
class ANColorWell: NSColorWell {
override func activate(_ exclusive: Bool) {
    NSColorPanel.shared.showsAlpha = true;
    super.activate(exclusive);
}

override func deactivate() {
    NSColorPanel.shared.showsAlpha = false;
    super.deactivate();

}
}
```

This is the swift4.0 version I tried, which I hope will be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

The answer, like dealing with most of AppKit, is to subclass.

```
@interface AlphaColorPanel : NSColorPanel

@end

@implementation AlphaColorPanel

- (BOOL)showsAlpha {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Then go into IB and override the class of the singular color panel you want to show the alpha slider.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I set the NSColorPanel for a NSColorWell? I can change the NSColorWell class name, but don't see any option to change the NSColorPanel class for that color well.

Comment: Looks like I can subclass NSColorWell and override the activate: and deactivate: method. That will probably do the trick. Thanks.