# How do I choose a clear color from a color picker?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscolorwell

I am using NSColorWell to let the user choose a color from a standard color picker. Even though the user can use choose colors I do not see a way for him to choose a clear color. The clear color choice is essential since I'm coloring closed Bezier paths, and sometimes I need fillColor to be transparent, hence the need to choose clear color. Any ideas of what to do?

Comment: [Add opacity slider to the color panel for one color well but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189074/add-opacity-slider-to-the-color-panel-for-one-color-well-but-not-others/15189852#15189852)

Comment: Set the showsAlpha property to true.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That solution is OK; the only thing I had to do was to remove [[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] close]; from my previous code.